# Beginner python question: Unresolved reference in function arguments (passing variables)

Tags: python, function

This is probably a question with a somewhat obvious answer, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

```py
def conv_pd_df():
    spreadsheet = client.open(spreadsheet_id).sheet1
    data = spreadsheet.get_all_values()
    index = str(data[0][0])
    headers = data.pop(0)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers, index=None)
    df = df.set_index(index)

    mask = df.applymap(lambda x: key in str(x))
    df1 = df[mask.any(axis=1)]
    return df1


def highlight(df1):
    for x in df1:
        print(x) # filler


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conv_pd_df()
    highlight(df1) # this is where the error is
```

I keep getting 'unresolved reference' in my `highlight(df1)` when trying to execute the code. I tried creating a blank pandas df = df1 at the very beginning to try to combat the issue but it still gives me the same error. I thought I passed the variables right, so what's going on here? this happens even when I don't put `if __name__ == '__main__':` and just run the functions directly too.

Comment: you might want to look into variable scope. This is a good introduction for example: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scope-of-variables-python

Comment: [Structure of a Program, Naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html),  [Names,objects,Scopes,Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) A lot of reading but it is important - refer to it every once and a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It starts with the code under `if __name__ == '__main__':` and you don't have a variable `df1` defined at that point. The `df1` in `conv_pd_df()` only exists in the scope of that function

You should set `df1` in your `__main__` equal to the return of `conv_pd_df()`

```py
df1  = conv_pd_df()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conv_pd_df()
    highlight(df1)
```

Granted, `conv_pd_df()` returns your `df1` dataframe, but you don't bind that return value, therefore there is no variable named `df1`.
The following will fix that reference issue:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df1 = conv_pd_df()
    highlight(df1)
```